# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle - You have requested a non-existent service "security.user_checker"

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use Symfony 2 and the FOSUserBundle. I can login, logout and view Profile.

**Problem:** When i go to "/register", fill out the form and press enter i get the following error:

**You have requested a non-existent service "security.user_checker".
500 Internal Server Error - ServiceNotFoundException**

It seems that I have do to some additional configuration or so, but I can't find anything about it.

Part of config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: fos_user
    user_class: Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User
```

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        fos_user:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        fos_user:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider:   fos_user
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: /secured/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**UPDATE**

Stack trace:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsGwF.png]

Comment: Is that the indentation in your config.yml? It could cause trouble.

Comment: No the indentation in my original files is right. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you make sure the FOSUserBundle version you are using is compatible with your version of Symfony? It bit me more than once.

Comment: @Louis-Philippe Huberdeau: I am using Symfony 2.0.9 and installed FOSUserBundle via symfony's "deps" file from "git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify a version for FOSUserBundle. The repository head is aligned with Symfony head, not 2.0.9.

```
[FOSUserBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git
    target=/bundles/FOS/UserBundle
    version=1.0.0
```

Comment: Always specify the version. It will save you a lot of pain when updating. In github, you can find the available versions under tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating FOSUserBundle (or any bundle for that matter) you need to make sure you mimic changes made in the FOSUserBundle to any files you overwrite.

In my particular case, in the RegistrationController FOSUserBundle changed a value from security.user_checker to fos_user.user_checker in the authenticateUser method, so I made the same change in my controller.

Every time you do an update of the vendors, you need to make sure files (controllers, services etc) you're overwriting in your bundle are not depending on a service class or method that has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you register services right ?
Or maybe You forgot add a routing for this service ?

Comment: I have added the following routes to my "app/routing.yml": [link](http://pastebin.com/RjwTdeut)

Comment: Which services do you mean? I have registered the bundle in [AppKernel.php](http://pastebin.com/SYAZDM7P)

Comment: And another, if your .yml files are formatted like in example, they wont work.

Comment: Dev environment. I cleared the cache - no change. The strange thing is that the user actually gets inserted into the database.